# How do i plot a pie chart of count of a certain value in a column

Tags: python

I have a column in my data called landmark, There are 5 different values of landmark that repeat multiple times. I want to group them and plot the count of them in a pie chart using python

Comment: Show us so code and the output when it failed

Comment: as a starting point you might have a look at: http://chrisalbon.com/python/matplotlib_pie_chart.html

Comment: I get unique values from

 cities=stations.landmark.unique()  stations is the name of my dataframe..and I get 5 unique values of the landmarks. I want to plot the count of these landmarks in that column.